# Flexslider showing 1px on right side of sliders

Tags: css

[image]

Hi,

I'm using a negative margin on the flexslider container so the 3 sliders can have a margin to the right only in the middle items not the far right in order to align flush with the top content.

It only shows sometimes when resizing the window, it seems like flexslider cannot calculate correctly because of the negative margin. Not sure how to get rid off this 1px on all screens.

http://dusit.syndacast.com/dusitprincess/korat/accommodation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change your code.

Please replace this code

```
.offer-list-div
{
    background-color:#f0eeef;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding: 1% 7% 20px;        
}
```

by this

```
.offer-list-div
{
    background-color:#f0eeef;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding: 1% 8% 20px;        
}
```

And your issue will be solved..

Let me know if issue still exists..thanx

Comment: Awesome you're the man! I wonder if you can fix the glitch when we click the arrow to right, you will see a grey box popup over the middle slider, can't seem to get rid of that too.

Comment: Am I the only one who can not see any difference between the two snippets ?

Comment: @phtrivier..it was 8 in second but after sec editing i wanted to copy other css but by mistake i copied whole..sorry for that and thanx for noticing

Comment: @user2760338 sorry but m not able to find grey box pop up..can you please show me in screenshot?

Comment: It's hard capture, it happens only when you click to the right and it slides across, after the slide animation is complete the grey box is gone, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @user2760338 please go in theme admin panel then Theme options > Homepage layout > Homepage Layout Manager and this little box is icon menu. You just have to move it into disable box. Read more from here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gray-box-below-homepage-slider